# get date only from a text with scrapy

Tags: python, date, scrapy

I have extracted a text which is a datetime from articles with scrapy, and from this text I want to get the date only.

the text looks like this:

```
" - Nov 13, 2021, 10:00 AM CST"
```

How can I extract the date only? which is  `Nov 13, 2021`

the current script I used to get the text is

```
'datetime': response.xpath('//*[@class="article_byline"]/text()[2]').get()
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using regex will work.  This pattern should do the trick `\w+?\s\d\d,\s\d{4}`

```
import re
datetime = response.xpath('//*[@class="article_byline"]/text()[2]').get()
date = re.search(r'\w+?\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}', datetime).group()
```

Out: 'Nov 13, 2021'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions):

```py
scrapy shell file:///PATH_TO_FILE/temp.html

In [1]: response.xpath('//*[@class="article_byline"]/text()[2]').re(r'[a-zA-Z]{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4}')[0]
Out[1]: 'Nov 13, 2021'
```